# Webchat updating when other user sends message

Tags: php, json

Im building a webchat using php and json. I know thats not the best solution but works for what im building.

So far users can send their messages and they get saved and displayed in the chat.

However the users need to manualy update the website to get new messages shown.

Is there anyway to detect file changes in php so that i can reload or rebuild the website.

Maybe checking the array length in the php file and then restarting the process again.

Can anybody please help me :)

Comment: `I know thats not the best solution`...that's certainly an understatement.

Comment: Rather than trying to make difficult workarounds, just use websockets or RTC for your chat like everyone else. And store the messages in a database or queue. File storage for interactive, real-time, frequently updated data is just always going to cause you problems. It's never going to be workable, even as a quick-and-dirty solution - it'll be dirty, but it certainly won't be quick (either to code, or to use).

Comment: For *realtime* chat I'd use WebRTC.